# Using bash script to compare two files and write new file

Tags: linux, bash

I am new to bash scripting and would like to write a bash script to do the following.
I have two tab delimited files as follows:

```
# file1 #
## position id 
.
.
.


# file2
## position type
. 
.
.
```

file 2 is a subset of file 1 with regard to the position column. 
I want to generate file3 such that for every line in file2, it looks up the line with the same position in file1 and writes out the following into file3

```
position id type
.
.
.
```

So, I want to essentially find the common positions between file1 and file2 (first column) and write them out along with their id and types (column 2 in the respective files).
I know how to do this using python but I would like to learn how to do a procedure like this using a bash script - i would appreciate any example code for the above problem.

> Extra note:

The values in each column are as follows

- position: chr1:887799
- id: R2A
- type: analphabeticstring

Thanks

Comment: Try the tools `join`, `cut` and `sort`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
join -a 1 <(sort file1) <(sort file2)
```

Should get you there

The man page of join has more background and samples:

- http://linux.die.net/man/1/join

Comment: thanks, i did not know about the join command. This worked well to solve the problem.

Comment: so this command actually did not do the job entirely correctly. It should have resulted in a file that was the same length as typefile but it resulted in a smaller file. I think this may be because the two files are not exactly the same on the position field (that is one is a subset of the other). I ended up using a python script with a hash - is there a simple way to doing using join (or another linux command) when one file is a subset of the other?

Comment: @msohail The manpage was there :) I edited to show how to make all rows from file1 be included.

Answer (score -1):

first, you need to make the files tab-separated, then it's as easy as

```
join -j 1 first.txt second.txt
```

Comment: need to ensure the input files are sorted on the join column